# matrix assignment from a matrix A to a matrix B using conditional statements based on a third matrix C

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two questions if you can kindly respond:

Q1) I have a matrix `choice`, where each person is making 4 of any possible choices, denoted as 1, 2, 3 and 4. 
I have three matrixes `A1`, `A2`, `A3` with income information for each person and each time period. Say I have n people and t time periods so `A1`, `A2`, `A3` are n-by-t and `choice` is n-by-t.

Now I want to make another matrix `B`, where `B` will pick the element from `A` according to the value in the choice matrix, i.e. if `choice(n,t)==1`, then `B(n,t) = A1(n,t)`. If `choice(n,t)==2`, then `B(n,t) = A2(n,t)`, and so on.

I have tried the for loop and the if statement, I am unable to do it. Please help.

Q2) I have a matrix `A` of incomes. `A` is dimension n-by-t. Some people have low income, some have high income. Say anyone with income<1000 is low and above 1000 is high. At the end of my simulations, I need to know whether each person was high income or low income. How can I make a high income and low income matrix from the bigger matrix?

Comment: I basically want to do this without the for loop. I did question 1 with the for loop, but it takes longer. However, Q2 I could not do

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far (that is, post some real code).

Answer (score 1):

Q1:

```
C = choice %else the code gets too long
B = A1 .* (C==1) + A2 .* (C==2) + A3 .* (C==3)
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle the value '4' in B if you only have A1 A2 A3, but this should work.

[EDIT]:
If the choice is '4', that element of B will be 0 for the B i defined above.

Q2:
this one's a little vague. Maybe this is what you wanted:

```
HighIncome = A > 1000
LowIncome = A <= 1000
```

If this doesn't do it, please explain your objective more precisely.

[EDIT]:
Based on your slightly less vague explanation on Q2 it sounds like you wan't something like this:

```
A_high_income = A .* (A > 1000)
A_low_income = A .* (A <= 1000)
CHOICE_high_income = choice .* (A > 1000)
CHOICE_high_income = choice .* (A <= 1000)
```

The high income matrices have zeros at the low-income positions and vice versa.
This doesn't make very much sens IMHO, but it's the closest I could get to your description.
If this doesn't do it, follow the instructions in my comment below and post some examples.

Comment: So in the high and low income, what I want is to pick people from the matrix A which are high income only and pick their corresponding rows from the choice matrix. The choice matrix tells us whether the person chooses sector 1, 2, 3 or 4. It is an n-by-t matrix. Then we have the matrix A of incomes which is also an n-by-t matrix that tells us the income in each sector. Now I want the income and the choice matrix separately for low income people and high income people. Can you please help again. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I still don't quite get what you mean. I would advise you to at least give an example of the matrix A, the choice matrix and the high- and low-income matrices you want. Make them 2x3 or something like that.
I don't quite understand what you mean when you say 'pick' and what 'format' your resulting matrices should be.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You can use three simple statements and some logical indexing.

```
B = A1;
B(choice == 2) = A2(choice == 2);
B(choice == 3) = A3(choice == 3);
```

Q2: To separate A and choice into two parts based on income, you first find the indices of "low income" rows and use that to get rows from the matrices.

```
lowIncomeNdx = any(A < 1000, 2);
lowIncome = A(lowIncomeNdx, :);
lowIncomeChoice = choice(lowIncomeNdx, :);
highIncome = A(~lowIncomeNdx, :);
highIncomeChoice = choice(~lowIncomeNdx, :);
```

Comment: So in the high and low income, what I want is to pick people from the matrix A which are high income only and pick their corresponding rows from the choice matrix. The choice matrix tells us whether the person chooses sector 1, 2, 3 or 4. It is an n-by-t matrix. Then we have the matrix A of incomes which is also an n-by-t matrix that tells us the income in each sector. Now I want the income and the choice matrix separately for low income people and high income people. Can you please help again. Thanks

Comment: @user1984196 What determines if a person is "high income"? Each person will have multiple income values in A, and some may be low and some may be high. It would really help a lot if you edit the original question to include example input and output matrices to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: if a person has income less than a certain number say 1000 in any cell in the income matrix he is low income.

Comment: @user1984196 I think my latest update does what you want. Please edit the question with the clarifying info you put in these comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get the exact corresponding choices from the choice matrix. The choices and income have to be for the same people. So we need to pick the same people from the choice matrix. Basically needing two matrices, lowinc, choice_lowinc, highinc, choice_highinc.